# How to remove users from Table1 which has more than 90 days from register date specified in Table2?

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I need `LEFT JOIN ON Table1.userid=Table2.id` and delete users from `Table1` which has more than 90 days since register date in `Table2.registerDate` (datetime format). How to build SQL query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
delete t1
    from table1 t1 join
         table2 t2
         on t1.userid = t2.id
    where t1.date > t2.registerdate + interval 90 day;
```

I am not sure if "90 days since" means before or after.  The above tests for dates that are 90 days after the register date.  `< t2.registerdate - interval 90 day` would be for "before".

Comment: Final query: `delete t1 from table1 t1 join
         table2 t2
         on t1.userid = t2.id
    where NOW() > t2.registerDate + interval 90 day;`. Big thanks!